# Horizontal centering for an absolutely positioned image

Tags: css, position, centering

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MtV9B/) is a fiddle with it centered, but the image with `position:relative` instead of `position:absolute`.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9nkDS/) is another fiddle with it positioned absolutely, but not centered.

Note that the image has a **variable width**.

The reason the image **must be centered** is because I want to fade one out while another is fading in behind it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: thanks, didn't find that in my search :) the 2nd solution worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution would be to not use the CSS position property at all.

Try displaying the images as block elements, and tell the browser to use an auto margin on left and right.

```
#imagesContainer img{
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Proof of concept fiddle (border added just so you can see that the image is in fact centered):
http://jsfiddle.net/9nkDS/5/

Comment: I need it to position absolutely so that I can fade images on top of the other.

Comment: I see that you found your solution. Be sure to give j08691 an upvote. :)